# Difference between these XPath expressions inside a Word Processing Markup Language?

Tags: .net, xpath, wordml

In Word Processing Markup Language (WordML) for Microsoft Office Word 2003, is there any difference between the following two XPath expressions:

```
@".//w:p[count(*/w:t) >= 0]"
```

and

```
@".//w:p"
```

I am confused because if the count is Zero, then what is the importance of the expression in the angular brackets? Doesn't both select the same number of nodes?

Also, does */w:t select only that are grandchildren or will it take into account the immediate children too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
".//w:p[count(*/w:t) >= 0]"
```

selects all descendants of the context node (`.`, whatever it is in the current state of processing) if they are elements with the qualified name `w:p` and only if their children (most likely `w:r` elements) have at least 0 `w:t`elements.

That does not make a lot of sense of course, but this would:

```
".//w:p[count(*/w:t) >= 1]"
```

But actually, this would be sufficient:

```
".//w:p[descendant::w:t]"
```

The rationale behind it is to select `w:p`elements only if they contain text (which is stored in `w:t` elements, which in turn is stored in `w:r` elements ("runs").

---

On the other hand,

```
".//w:p"
```

selects all `w:p` elements that are descendants of the context node, regardless of whether they in turn contain a `w:t` descendant or not.

---

**EDIT**

> Doesn't both select the same number of nodes?

Yes, both amount to the same, but one of them is a sensible expression whereas the other is not.

> does */w:t select only that are grandchildren or will it take into account the immediate children too?

This expression will only take into account `w:t` elements that are *grandchildren* of `w:p`. Besides, this (i.e. `w:t`as an immediate child of `w:p`) is not allowed in the OOXML Schema.

Comment: So, above two expressions will return the same number of nodes?

Comment: Disregarding this WordML, Does in XPath, generally, * will select only the grand children? * here means >=0 or >1 ?

Comment: No, absolutely not. `*` in an expression selects the _children_ of an element, not the grandchildren. I don't understand your last question I'm afraid.

Comment: Not using * alone, if I use */a, then will it select 'a' that are only grand children or 'a' that can be children or grand children?

Comment: Then, it will _only_ select elements that are _grandchildren_ of the current element (as I have already said in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the predicate [count(X) >= 0] is always true and can therefore be safely eliminated.